# Slack web-api returning channel not found chat.postMessage to a private channel

Tags: javascript, http, post, slack-api

I have the following code which returns me the following error. The error says channel not found, howerver I am following the docs for a private channel to either use the name of the channel or to use the string that is in the url with a G at the beginning. I have given the correct chat write permissions to the bot for the channel and am using the correct bot api generated toekn, I was able to post via webhook before but I want to use the web-api.

This is the docs I am referring to https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#channels

```
const { WebClient } = require('@slack/web-api');
const token = process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN;
const web = new WebClient(token);

const conversationId = 'private-channel-name'; & tried this instead 'GCV2FGELX'

    const result = await web.chat.postMessage({
        text: 'Hello world!',
        channel: conversationId,
    });
```

This is the error response I am getting

```
{
  code: 'slack_webapi_platform_error',
  data: {
    ok: false,
    error: 'channel_not_found',
    response_metadata: { scopes: [Array], acceptedScopes: [Array] }
  }
}
```

I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong, but doing a little digging, even when I try to use the tester get request for groups.list here https://api.slack.com/methods/groups.list/test with a auth token with the correct permissions I just get a empty response back, vs a list of groups.
Not sure here.

I did note that it said this `Post into any channel it has access to` for what the bot can do how do I know what channel's the bot has access to. I have given it write permissions to my whole orginization?

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you trying adding the BOT to the private channel as an APP (You find this under the Channel Details >> More >> Add Apps. Hope that will solve your issue.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I too had faced the same issue.

Did you trying adding the BOT/APP to the private channel (You find this under the Channel Details >> More >> Add Apps.

[image: Slack Channel Detail Screen Shot]

Once you have added your BOT/APP to the channel. Your messages will be getting posted into the channel.

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: facing the same issue but this time it's for DM of the bot

Comment: @manasvi Can you provide some more details.

Comment: @manasvi Will also suggest you to take a look at "Post to a direct message channel" in https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage . Hope that might be of some help.

Comment: Thanks! Helped me with my slash command. Now what about slash commands to other users (i.e., DMing someone and using a slash command to fetch information). I still get `channel_not_found`.

Comment: 2 years and they haven't updated an error message that says "your bot isn't in the channel"

Answer (score 10):

Still ran into this in 2022 with slack bolt.

The error slack_webapi_platform_error with error channel_not_found seems to mean that there is no ACCESS to this channel because app needs to be specifically added to this private channel. Thanks @Anumoy Sutradhar

Here a newer screenshot (not possible to add in comments):
[image]

The modal opens when you click on the channel name.